# Asp.net core force user to confirm email

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-identity

Like in the title I am trying to force the user to confirm the email before let him log in. I was doing things according to Microsoft tutorial and there was wrote that I have to add

> o.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;

what I have done but it do not block me to log in even I did not confirm my email

```
 services.AddIdentity<Company, IdentityRole>
      (o =>
      {
        // configure identity options
        o.Password.RequireDigit = false;
        o.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
        o.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
        o.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
        o.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
        o.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
        o.Tokens.EmailConfirmationTokenProvider = EmailConfirmationTokenProviderName;
      })
      .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ShopContext>()
      .AddTokenProvider<ConfirmEmailDataProtectorTokenProvider<Company>>(EmailConfirmationTokenProviderName);
```

I am using jwt tokens authentication have I do something more in this case than things which I show?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add checking if account is confirmed in start of `Login` action

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
        if (user != null)
        {
            if (!await _userManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, 
                              "You must have a confirmed email to log in.");
                return View(model);
            }
        }
```

Also remember about prevent newly registered users from being automatically logged by comment `await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);` in `Register` action

For more read [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm)

Comment: I already do things like you show, so is there any reason to add this line 
o.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;?

Comment: `SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;` is sending mail with activation link. This link is necessary when you applied code above to login, because without activation you can't login

Comment: @J. Doe - many thanks for your answer, it was exactly what I was looking for. I was thinking about improving if further. What if I would like to distinguish users that have not confirmed the email and the ones that are not admin confirmed? I was thinking about extending the SignInResult and creating a new result. Then I would hide the SignIn methods with the new ones calling base and checking additionaly for AdminConfirmed. Would that make sense?